# New Dataframe column based on if statement and other columns

Tags: python, lambda

I am working with the below dataframe, called df_atr_check:

```
Symbol  Average Price   ATR Quantity
SBUX          56          2       100
AAPL         150          3      -200
GOOG         700          4       300
```

I am trying to create a new column in my data frame with the name "Mental Stop".

Conditions are very straight forward:
If the quantity is > 0, then the Mental Stop value will be "Average Price" - "ATR", else, it will be "Average Price" + "ATR".

I am trying to use a Lambda function here, however, it doesn't return a value for me. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
df_atr_check["Mental Stop"] = lambda x: (df_atr_check["Average Price"] - df_atr_check["ATR Multiple"]) if df_atr_check["Quantity"] > 0 else (df_atr_check["Average Price"] + df_atr_check["ATR Multiple"])
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you just want to get that functionality, you can do it without lambda. For instance: df_atr_check["Mental Stop"] = df_atr_check["Average Price"] + (1-2*( df_atr_check["Quantity"] > 0))*df_atr_check["ATR Multiple"] True is coerced into 1 and False is coerced into 0, so (1-2*( df_atr_check["Quantity"] > 0) evaluates to -1 if quantity > 0 and 1 if quantity <=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Silly me. Thanks anyways!

```
    df_atr_check["Mental Stop"] = df_atr_check.transform(lambda x: (x["Average Price"] - x["ATR Multiple"]) \
    if x["Quantity"] > 0 else (x["Average Price"] + x["ATR Multiple"]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions can be great for situations like this, provided that the if conditions don't get too complex. Lamdas will achieve the same end, but list comprehensions are easier to read (in my opinion).

Try this...

```
df_atr_check['Mental Stop'] = [x - y if z > 0 else x + y for x,y,z in zip(df_atr_check['Average Price'], df_atr_check['ATR Multiple'], df_atr_check['Quantity'])]
```